# Regex for finding empty anchor tags

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I'm looking for a regular expression that is finding all empty anchor tags within any html string. "Empty" is meant as no text node within itself or in any of its children.

For example, these should be found:

```
<p>abc<a href="http://foo.com"></a>def</p>
<p>abc<a href="http://foo.com"><span></span></a>def</p>
<p>abc<a href="http://foo.com"><span><b></b></span></a>def</p>
```

And these not:

```
<p>abc<a href="http://foo.com">Some text</a>def</p>
<p>abc<a href="http://foo.com"><span></span></a>def</p>
<p>abc<a href="http://foo.com">Some<span><b>Text</b></span></a>def</p>
```

The regex should be POSIX-compatible (I need it for MySQL).

Why?
I need it to remove empty anchors in a mysql table column (with pure MySQL) with a helping custom regex_replace function and honestly I don't know a better way to achieve this. MySQLs `UpdateXML` does not work for multiple matches at once.

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I need to lookup a  mysql table with a field containing html code and need to replace empty anchors - with pure MySQL. Do you know any other way?

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with regexes will lead to sorrow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is: to not do it. [Parsing HTML with regex is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), instead I'm using a combination of [PHPs SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) class to navigate through the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
/<a href=.*?><\/a>/
```

Comment: I don't think POSIX regexes support lazy search. Try [^>]*

Comment: This won't work because it's only finding empty anchor tags not those with other empty tags in it (see the examples in my post above).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this pattern it works in your condition

```
<[^/>]+>[ \n\r\t]*</[^>]+>
```